# Calling a JPanel inside a split panel Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jsplitpane

Hi I'm having trouble in my code. I can't call or display my JPanel(TruthTable) inside my splitpane in the Minimize class when I click the button and Keypressed(Enter).The problem is in the class Minimize

*UPDATE: I'have solved my problem regarding to diplaying the panel my next problem is when I call the constructor the text in the panel should be updated.I also change the setText to append 'coz they say that JPanel doesnt support setText.I've already used,validate,repaint method but no luck in updating the textArea.

[image]

Heres my code for class Minimize:

```
package splashdemo;

public class Minimize extends JPanel implements ClipboardOwner
{

      simButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            LogicGates lg= new LogicGates();
            lg.geth();
            sim s=new sim();
            s.InputExp(lg.g,lg.g1);
            s.menu();
            s.setSize(700,700);
            s.setVisible(false);
            Frame f = new Frame();
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            f.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
            f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new sim());
            f.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
            f.setSize(580, 500);
            panel.add(s.button);
            f.show();
            f.setVisible(false);


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b);
ex=b;
cAppend();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex1);
InToPost(ex1);
        foutput= doTrans();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, foutput);

             TruthTable_1 kl = new TruthTable_1(foutput);

            Minimize mi = new Minimize();
             s.InputExp(lg.g,lg.g1);
             s.menu();
            lg.gatessplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, mi, lg.p1);

//here's the splitpane where I should display the TruthTable_1 panel but it doesn't diplay
          lg.p1.add(lg.gatessplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, s,kl));
            lg.gatessplit.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            lg.gatessplit.setDividerLocation(250);
            lg.gatessplit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 500));
            lg.createAndShowGUI();


        }});


    }
```

Heres my code the TruthTable_1:constructors

```
public TruthTable_1() {
      super();
tableArea.append("This is a Test");
      //setBackground(Color.black);
    createg();

      setVisible(true);
    }
        public void createg(){
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        line= 0;
        truth= 'T';
        fallacy= 'F';
        final JPanel top= new JPanel();
        input= new TextField(35);
        TFCheck= new Checkbox("Select for \"1/0\" (default\"T/F\")");
        check= new JButton("Check");
        check.addActionListener(this);

        top.add(input);
        top.add(TFCheck);
        top.add(check);
                top.setVisible(false);
        tableArea= new JTextArea(16, 40);
        tableArea.setEditable(false);
        tableArea.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        // all letters are the same width in this font

        go= new JButton("Do it to it!");
        go.addActionListener(this);
        input.addActionListener(this);
                go.setVisible(false);
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        scrolls= new JScrollPane(tableArea);// add scroll buttons to the area
        add(scrolls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(go, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(535, 500);
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        }
    public TruthTable_1(String f){
            createg();

                 tableArea.append(run(f));

    }
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: Uh, this is too long. Can you post a SSCE that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @JakubZaverka I've already edited the code and I've specified the line of code where I will display it.

Comment: I've tried to put setVisible(true) and also repaint , validate but it doesn't display

Comment: Search for `main()` failed. Please read the tutorial cited by @Moonbeam and  edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: And in the example, please don't name your fields/variables "s" "lg" or "p1", those names are not very informative.

Comment: @JakubZaverka sorry it's just a temp variables,next time I will name it correctly. By the way how can I update the text in the textarea?I've used the validate, repaint methods but nothing happened.